# Order List of SelectItem based on value in java

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using Primefaces 5.1 with JSF 2.2.

I need to ordered List of SelectItemList based on selectItem value.

```
List<SelectItem>mainList=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
mainList.add(new SelectItem("1&Val1","Kumar"));
mainList.add(new SelectItem("4&Val4","Raju"));
mainList.add(new SelectItem("5&Val5","Suriya"));
mainList.add(new SelectItem("3&Val3","Kamal"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by `SelectItem` value? `SelectItem` seem to contain two strings in it ...

Comment: Using `SelectItem` is not needed anymore in recent JSF versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a way to order the `SelectItem` class. You can do that by implementing the `Comparable` interface and overriding the `compareTo` method.

```
class SelectItem implements Comparable<SelectItem> {

    // constructor, getters, setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SelectItem other) {
        // implement logic that compares the values of the class the way that you want

        // maybe like this
        if(this.getValue() > other.getValue()) {
            return 1;
        } else if(this.getValue() < other.getValue()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0; // values are equal
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Collections.sort()` to sort your list of items.

```
List<SelectItem>mainList=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
mainList.add(new SelectItem("1&Val1","Kumar"));
mainList.add(new SelectItem("4&Val4","Raju"));
mainList.add(new SelectItem("5&Val5","Suriya"));
mainList.add(new SelectItem("3&Val3","Kamal"));

Collections.sort(mainList); // now they are sorted
```